# ImageMagick - create gif with last image as a preview

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I can create a gif, but I'd like the last image to be the preview image. What option can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I presume you are referring to an *animated* GIF? If so, I guess you mean the first frame when you refer to the *preview image*, so I guess the answer is to put a copy of the last frame first. So please clarify that and edit your question (not in `comments` area) to show your actual command. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
convert -resize 30% -delay 10 -loop 0 -fuzz 10% -layers Optimize `find ./myFolder -type f | grep .png | sort | tail -1 ; find ./myFolder -type f | grep .png | sort | tail -5 ;` myGif.gif
```

The inside commands (between ``) finds the latest file and the previous 5 files (including the latest file). i.e  file#5, file#1, file#2, file#3, file#4, file#5 in that order. This is so that the last file is also the preview image. Typically the first image is the preview image.

- -resize 30%: Resizes the png files
- -delay 10: 10 fps (ticks per second)
- -loop 0: Sets it to an infinite loop
- -layers Optimize : Not sure exactly what this does
- -fuzz 10%: Colors within 10% of the intensity values are considered equal. This actually halves the file size